# Advice for a spaceship landing special effects?

Tags: particles, effects

So, I am decent at modeling and animation but NEVER done special effects before, but am working on a spaceship animation and want it to land, but have it kicking up dust as it is landing, similar to a helicopter (circular and outward dust clouds) but since I have very little experience in VFX, I have no clue where to start, and unfortunately Blender VFX tutorials involving dust seem very few and far between. Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you need to use a smoke simulation if you want something realistic